Why can't I toggle my custom legends on or off in Plotly?
I have a function that creates subplots with multiple axes on each subplot using custom code, as multiple axes are not currently supported. I can't paste all the code here as it is a lot, but, at a glance, I create multiple subplots using make_subplots, and then created extra axes when needed. Traces are created and assigned to their appropriate axes.
With the figure complete, I align the legends with each subplot. I achieve this using code inspired from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/78413566/18880077. This is how it looks:
rows = 4
cols = 1
horiz_spacing = 0.1
vert_spacing = 0.1
subplot_height = (1 - (rows - 1) * vert_spacing) / rows
subplot_width = (1 - (cols - 1) * horiz_spacing) / cols

for row in range(1, 5):
    x = subplot_width
    y = 1 - ((row - 1) * (subplot_height + vert_spacing))
    fig.update_traces(selector={"xaxis": f"x{row if row>1 else ''}"}, legend=f"legend{row+1}")
    fig.update_layout({f"legend{row+1}": dict(y=y, xanchor='left', yanchor="top")})

This code works, and I end up with a figure like the one below. All seems well, but if I click on the legends, nothing happens. I cannot toggle them on or off as usual. The cursor indicates that I can click on it, but nothing follows.
Why can't I toggle custom legends?
Figure with custom legends aligned with subplots

Without a minimally reproducible example, it's difficult to provide any meaningful coding help. Try editing your question.
